# Integral basis of an extension of number fields

Tags: commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K\subseteq F$ be number fields with ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K\le \mathcal{O}_F$.

**Question:** Is $\mathcal{O}_F$ a free $\mathcal{O}_K$-module ?

By the integral basis theorem this is true when $K=\mathbb{Q}$ but I don't know about the general case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. The following notes from Keith Conrad's website give a family of examples with $\mathscr{O}_F$ not $\mathscr{O}_K$-free:

http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/notfree.pdf

Comment: Great. Thank you very much.