# Is $O_L$ a free $O_K$ module?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

This must have been known. Let $L/K$ be a finite number field extension. Then is $O_L$ a free $O_K$ module? How to prove it if so? So far, I know how to prove the following: 
Let $\alpha_1,\dotsc,\alpha_n\in O_L$ be a $K$-basis of $L$ and let $d=d_{L/K}(\alpha_1,\dotsc,\alpha_n)$. Then $dO_L\subset O_K\alpha_1\oplus\dotsm\oplus O_K\alpha_n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. This question has been answered before [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/245607/integral-basis-of-an-extension-of-number-fields?rq=1) by linking to
[these notes from Keith Conrad](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/notfree.pdf).

Comment: OK. We can find $\beta_1\dotsc,\beta_n\in L$ such that $O_L\subset O_K\beta_1\oplus \dotsm\oplus O_K\beta_n$. But some of these $\beta_1,\dotsc,\beta_n$ may not be in $O_L$. But can we at least ask one of them in $O_L$? What I want to know is: can we find $\beta_2,\dotsc,\beta_n\in L$ such that $O_L\subset O_K1\oplus O_K\beta_2\oplus\dotsm \oplus O_K\beta_n$?